# VLC mutes sound after seeking on Pop! OS

Tags: linux, audio, video, vlc-media-player

I noticed this issue when I was playing videos with VLC. When the video is originally opened, there is absolutely no visible problem.
However, seeking (with the mouse's cursor or the arrows of the keyboard) will eventually cause the video to go silent (it can take several seeking actions, sometimes just one, sometimes dozens). The image is still correctly decoded but the sound is muted. I noticed that I it then impossible to play videos on youtube after VLC has stopped producing sound, the videos simply won't start after hitting play and are frozen on the first frame.

I was able to reproduce this problem while seeking in MP4 and AVI videos, but also in MP3 audio files.

What appears to be the same issue was already described here [sound - VLC player mutes when seeking - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549306/vlc-player-mutes-when-seeking) but the solution (forcing ALSA audio output and Device to PulseAudio Sound Server) does not work for me.

The log from VLC indicates

```
main debug: Buffering 98%
main debug: Buffering 99%
main debug: Stream buffering done (7950 ms in 33 ms)
main debug: end of video preroll
main debug: Decoder wait done in 42 ms
main warning: timing screwed (drift: 170754 us): stopping resampling
main warning: playback way to late (195921): flushing buffers
alsa error: cannot estimate delay: Input/ouput error
main warning: playback way to early (-1109222): playing silence
```

I have no idea if this is a VLC-related problem (so far I had this problem only with VLC and not with another madia player) or an ALSA-related problem. As I am fairly new to linux, I don't know how to troubleshoot the audio system.
I noticed that typing

```
 systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse; rm -r ~/.config/pulse
```

as indicated [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/) restores the sound, until the next seeking glitch.

I use Pop!OS 22.04 and VLC 3.0.18. The infos of `alsa-info` are available [here](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b338867c3fc2c4813e3d287a37ae69577039184)

Thank you.